# How to make Passport.js work in Adonis Framework

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware, adonis.js

I wanted to know if `Passport.js` can ONLY be used in an `Express framework` and not in any other? The docs doesn't completely answer my question. I'm in the middle of migrating my project from Express to `Adonis.js` and I can't seem to make passport work. Here is a sample of my code:

```js
const passport = use('passport')  
const bearer = use('./bearer')

passport.use('bearer', bearer)

module.exports = passport
```

and here is how I register it:

```js
const namedMiddleware = {
  auth: 'Adonis/Middleware/Auth',
  guest: 'Adonis/Middleware/AllowGuestOnly',
  bearer: passport.authenticate(['bearer'], { session: false }),
}
```

this is the usage (I provided a bearer token):

```js
Route.post('/', ({ response }) => {
  response.json('Hello world')
}).middleware(['bearer'])
```

It does not work. Error about res.setHeader is not a function showing. Maybe because the resoponse and http structure is different in adonis?

I know that Adonis has its own authentication library but my **INITIAL** goal is to get what I have now in Express to work in an Adonis environment before making any library changes to avoid any complications.

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated from knex to adonis.js as well. Integrating passport.js was initially painful but I get it to work with Macros.

For your error, Adonis' Request object has no setHeader. You will need to create a macro on Request for that function. Something like this

```
function setHeader (name, value) {
  this.header(name, value)
}
Response.macro('setHeader', setHeader)
```

Add that to a provider or hooks and you should be all set.